# Laravel, Swiftmailer error: Class does not exist

Tags: php, forms, email, laravel, swiftmailer

I have a form

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'submit.contactAct', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}

            {{ Form::label('fremail', trans('people.email')) }} <span class="req">*</span>
            {{ Form::text('fremail', Input::old('fremail'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            {{ $errors->first('fremail', '<span class="help-block alert alert-danger">:message</span>') }}

            {{ Form::label('comment', trans('people.contact messages')) }} <span class="req">*</span>
            {{ Form::textarea('comment', Input::old('comment'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => 5)) }}
            {{ $errors->first('comment', '<span class="help-block alert alert-danger">:message</span>') }}

            {{ Form::hidden('email', $actor['email']) }}

            {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}

        {{ Form::close() }}
```

It has three fields: a from email field ('fremail'), a 'comment' field and a 'email' field which grabs the email from the 'actor' database table.

My submit function looks like this.  It validates the data and sends it to a send function.  It also creates a $star variable and stores the 'email' field.  For this example the email stored in $star=actorname@gmail.com

```
public function submitContactAct()
{

    //prepare input
    $input = Input::except('_token');
            $star = Input::get('email');

    if ( ! $this->validator->with($input)->passes())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($this->validator->errors())->withInput($input);
    }


    $this->mailer->sendContactUsAct($input, $star);

    return Redirect::back()->withSuccess( trans('main.contact success') );
}
```

This is my send email function, I have set the setReplyTo to the $star variable, but I keep receiving 
Class actorname@gmail.com does not exist

```
public function sendContactUsAct(array $input, $star)
{
       //get contact us email for db

            $options = App::make('Options');
    $email = $options->getContactEmail();

    if ($email)
    {
        Mail::send('Emails.ContactAct', $input, $star, function($message) use($email)
        {
                    $message->setReplyTo($star);
            $message->to($email)->subject( trans('main.contact email subject') );
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know why it is thinking a the string in $star is a class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Mail::send('Emails.ContactAct', $input, function($message) use ($email, $star)
{
    $message->setReplyTo($star);
    message->to($email)->subject( trans('main.contact email subject') );
});
```

Variable `$star` has to be passed using `use` because it's not in scope of your closure.